# Xamarin Studio iOS: UIImagePickerController Camera, Hide controls in landscape mode

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to allow taking a photo only in portrait mode.
My idea is to hide the controls in landscape mode.
The problem is, if I rotate the iPad in portrait mode, the controls are visibel, but the take photo button is not touchable. Any ideas?

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotate ()
{
        Console.WriteLine (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation);

        switch (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation) {

        case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
        case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
            this.ShowsCameraControls = false;
            this.AllowsEditing = false;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait:
        case UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
            this.ShowsCameraControls = true;
            this.AllowsEditing = true;


            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 screenshots, starting camera in portrait mode-> Button working, after rotating in landscape, controls disappearing as expected, then rotating it back to portrait, the controls appearing, but looking different and the take photo button is not working.

[image]
[image]